# Multiple Nested IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, formatting, nested, conditional-statements

I have the following issue:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(W7=0, "Today", ""), IF(W7=1, "Tomorrow", ""), IF(W6="Completed", "Completed", ""), IF(W7<=-1, "Late ", ""))
```

Now, if W7 is 0,1 or <=-1 my output column will show `Today`, `Tomorrow` or `Late` and if W6 says Completed it will show `Completed`.

Issue:
Now if W7 says `0` and W6 says `Completed` it says "TodayCompleted". However what I am looking for is that if it says completed, it takes priority and it will ignore the W7 value. Meaning, if W6 is completed, it will ignore anything inside the W7 and just show `Completed`. If W6 is empty, it will show the W7 value.

I would love to have help on this and sincerely appreciate anyone who could shed some light on this using a formula, or even better with conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If W6 takes priority, you should address it first.

```
=IF(W6="Completed", "Completed", IF(W7=0,"Today",IF(W7<=-1,"Late",IF(W7=1,"Tomorrow","")))&W6)
```

Note that in Excel, the & symbol can be used to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d) is even in there as there seems to be a pick-one-and-ignore-the-rest approach. I would use an `IF` to give precedence to what is in W6 and pass over to a [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-9470906c-59c5-4848-9442-dad062e67203) if W6 doesn't meet expectations.

```
=IF(W6="Completed", W6, LOOKUP(W7, {-1E+99,0,1,2;"Late","Today","Tomorrow",""}))
```

If W6 is *Completed* then return what is in W6. If not then base the return on what is in W7. Your original formula provided a default blank string if no conditions were matched and I've reproduced that in the case that W6 is not *Completed* and W7 is greater than *1*.

Answer (score 0):

> even better with conditional formatting

Set up four rules as below:

[image: SO29425554 example]

Taking one of these as an example:

Select (the cell in) your output column (here assumed to be X7) HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=W7=1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> with Custom, Type `"Tomorrow"`, OK, OK. You may also need to enter something in X7 (I suggest `-`).

Repeat above for other rules.

Because there are two trigger cells (W6 and W7) you may need to decide which has priority where both are populated, so change the order in which the rules are applied (what the up and down arrows in the image are for), or check `Stop If True`.

You may also need to apply anchors (`$`s) to your formulae and change the `Applies to` range if you want the formatting to apply to more than a single cell.